Open/Save Rich Text file "File format not valid" error
I'm new to C# and currently trying to make a rich text editor with tabs. It saves files with edited text correctly, but when I'm trying to open them in apllicaton (or any rtf or txt file in general), I get an error message: "File format is not valid".
 public partial class RichText : Form
 {
     private string currentFilePath = null;
     private string FileName = string.Empty;
     string altText;
     string curDir;
     bool izmText = false;
     public RichText()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
         saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Plain Text (*.txt)|*.txt|Rich Text Format (*.rtf)|*.rtf";
     }

     private RichTextBox GetRichTextBox()
     {
         RichTextBox rtb = null;
         TabPage tp = tabControl1.SelectedTab;

         if (tp != null)
         {
             rtb = tp.Controls[0] as RichTextBox;
         }
         return rtb;
     }

     //open
     private void openToolStripMenuItem1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
             OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
             openFileDialog1.Filter = "Plain Text (*.txt)|*.txt|Rich Text Format (*.rtf)|*.rtf";
             openFileDialog1.Title = "Select a File";
             if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
             {
                 currentFilePath = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                 GetRichTextBox().LoadFile(currentFilePath, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
             }
     }

     //save as
     private void saveToolStripMenuItem1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
         try
         {
             if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentFilePath))
             {
                 if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
                     return;
                 currentFilePath = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
                 GetRichTextBox().SaveFile(currentFilePath, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
             }
             tabControl1.SelectedTab.Text = Path.GetFileName(currentFilePath); // Set tab text to the file name

         }
     }

Would really appticiate any help.
